# Bootstrap model is not rendering properly with latest 'bootstrap-scss' gem in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to write Ajax code to render a model form. So, I tried with sample code from web which was written in 'bootstrap-sass 2.3.2.2', where it is working fine. 
[image]

But, when I tried with latest 'bootstrap-sass 3.3.0.1' (configured as per the bootstrap-sass configuration), it is not working in rails 4. Here is the model how it looks like. Sometimes I see the model is not launching at all. 
[image]

Here is my configuration settings:

"Gem" file:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

"assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_config.scss":

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Please help me with the correct configuration. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap v3 is not backward-compatible with Bootstrap v2. You'll need to port your webpages to v3 by following the official migration guide: http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

Among many other changes, the HTML required for Bootstrap modals is different in v3.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

After migrating the code to v3, it is working fine..

Old code (bootstrap-sass v2.3.2.2):

```
<div id="productModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <!-- Model Title -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <!-- Footer -->
  </div>    
</div>
```

New (working) code (bootstrap-sass v3.3.0.1):

```
<div id="productModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="productModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <!-- Model Title -->
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="productModalTitle">Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Content -->
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <!-- Footer -->
          </div>    

      /div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```